# "Classname" not declared in this scope (c++)

Tags: c++

I have a class SetStructure with this .h file:

```
#ifndef setstructure_h
#define setstructure_h
#include "Matrix.h"

class SetStructure {
    public:
        SetStructure();
        //some other functions
};

#endif
```

And a training class with this .h file:

```
#ifndef training_h
#define training_h
#include "SetStructure.h"
#include "Matrix.h"

class Training {
    private:
        //some functions
    public:
        //some functions
};

#endif
```

When I compile everything, I get this error in my implementation file for Training:

```
SetStructure training = new SetStructure();
```

This gives an error

```
'SetStructure' was not declared in this scope.
```

Furthermore the compiler thinks all my functions in Training return `int` even though they're specified as other return types in the Training.h file.

Is there some problem with my `#include` statements or something else which might lead to this issue?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You need to forward declare SetStructure at the start of the Training class, put `class SetStructure;` after the includes, and before the `class Training {` lines.

Comment: @EvanCarslake There's no evidence that's necessary here.

Comment: @aschepler true, I just thought it might be worth trying, even though the header file is included...

Comment: The first thing to check is that `training.h` is actually `#include`d by `training.cpp`.   The second thing to check is that `SetStructure training = new SetStructure()` is invalid, regardless of anything else - an object cannot generally be initialised using a `new` expression.

Comment: Turns out the issue was there were some old .h.gch files in the folder from when I probably accidentally pressed compile on a .h file. In the old files the #include statement wasn't present.